Tag wiki for [testflight] needs a cleanup by someone familiar with it
While reviewing this suggested edit I noticed the TestFlight wiki is in a bit of a confusing state. It presently refers to TestFlight in the past tense ("TestFlight was a developer tool...") and says that "The service was terminated on February 26, 2015".
Meanwhile I observe that https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ is live and talks about the service in the present tense, and that we are getting multiple new testflight questions per month.
I have only ever briefly dipped my toes into iOS development and so am not familiar enough to understand the history here, nor can I quickly make sense of it by looking at Wikipedia, but our Wiki seems either wrong, incomplete, or misleading; it suggests that the entire service the tag refers to was shut down and no longer exists, but evidently this is not the case. (Unless, I suppose, the pre-2015 TestFlight that was shut down and the one that exists today are actually best understood as two completely different services that confusingly share a name?)
The suggested edit, prepending a paragraph about TestFlight in the present tense, doesn't really satisfactorily resolve the situation. Before, the content was coherent but seemingly wrong; with the edit, the content is simply incoherent, first referring to TestFlight in the present tense as a currently available service and then in the very next paragraph referring to it in the past tense as something that has been shut down, without explaining the apparent contradiction.
I'm sure we must have some folks here on Meta who have been working in iOS development regularly for the last decade, are entirely familiar with the history here, and can explain it and suggest how to fix the Wiki (and perhaps suggest other changes if appropriate - e.g. was the pre-2015 TestFlight actually a totally different service that ought to have a separate tag?); could one of them please go ahead and clean this up?

I think I've pieced together what happened here. So when the tag excerpt say "terminated" it's wrong, according to wayback machine's copy of the linked page it was actually "moved to iTunes Connect" (which was later rebranded to App Store Connect). I'll let people more familiar with iOS development confirm though.

@MetaAbdulAzizBarkat I wasn't sure after seeing the specific archived page that you link to, but flicking through the capture history of the URL https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ on the Wayback Machine is perhaps even more instructive. It seems to have been continuously live since 2015, and continuously used the name "TestFlight". So it doesn't seem like the service or the name has ever been retired - just some of the web-based stuff got moved around, and for some reason the SDK stopped being necessary.

@MetaAbdulAzizBarkat (i.e. I agree with you that the claim that it was "terminated" is misleading/wrong. If nobody with more expertise weighs in, I am inclined to nuke the entire existing Wiki, which is already pretty confusing, and replace it with just the paragraph the suggested editor wanted to add in https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36588951. But I'll hold off for a week on doing that in case anyone with more expertise wants to salvage the confusing account of the history given in the current Wiki instead of just throwing it away.)

TestFlight used to be an independent service from Apple, but then Apple acquired it (Ref: https://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple)
So in short, pre 2015 is one service that shares the name with the current TestFlight provided by Apple (And built on top of the old service).
Recent questions are referring to this Apple service and old questions should be referring to the old service. I don't have enough experience in the meta part of StackOverflow to suggest on how to proceed forward, just providing context as someone with iOS dev exp.
